# empty ListView, how can I show a message on a ListView when it's empty?

Tags: android, listview

I'm developing an Android application.

Is there any way to show a message on a ListView only with it's empty?

I'm using a custom ArrayAdapter, so I have to create a specific object with the text I want to show.

I'm wondering if there is a specific field on ListView to setup a message when it's empty.

Any advice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See the documentation of [ListActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html):

> Optionally, your custom view can
>   contain another view object of any
>   type to display when the list view is
>   empty. This "empty list" notifier must
>   have an id "android:empty". Note that
>   when an empty view is present, the
>   list view will be hidden when there is
>   no data to display.